Why can every linear conditionally unbiased estimator of the regression coefficient be written as a weighted sum of the independent variables?
I'm studying Stock and Watson's Introduction to Econometrics, and just reached the part in which they discuss the Gauss-Markov Theorem. They make a statement that is very easy to accept, but I'm having a hard time finding a formal justification for it.
For context, we are talking about simple linear regression $Y_i = \beta_0 +\beta_1 X_i + u_i$. The statement is: "If $\tilde{\beta_1}$ is a linear estimator, then it can be written as $\widetilde{\beta}_1=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i Y_i,\text { where the weights } a_1, \ldots, a_n \text { can depend on } X_1, \ldots, X_n \text { but not on } Y_1, \ldots, Y_n \text {. }$
I know that this is a dumb question, but could anyone give me a light on why a linear estimator must be linear on the independent variable, rather than linear on both the independent and dependent variables?

What you are seeking is the concept of estimability.
In the case of a linear model $\mathbf Y=\mathbf X\boldsymbol \beta+\boldsymbol\varepsilon, $ a linear function of parameters $\boldsymbol\lambda^\top\boldsymbol\beta$ is (linearly) estimable if there exists a vector $\bf a$ such that $$\mathbb E[\mathbf a^\top\mathbf Y]=\boldsymbol\lambda^\top\boldsymbol\beta;$$ if $\bf Y$ is replaced by $\mathbf X\boldsymbol \beta+\boldsymbol\varepsilon$ in the above relation, this would yield $\mathbf a^\top\mathbf X=\boldsymbol\lambda^\top, $ that is, $\boldsymbol\lambda \in\mathcal C(\mathbf X^\top). $ In that vein, $\rm[II]$ sums up:

linear functions of parameters that are identifiable are estimable and have linear unbiased estimators.

--
References:
$\rm[I]$ Design and Analysis of Experiments, Vol. $1, $ Klaus Hinkelmann, Oscar Kempthorne, John Wiley & Sons, $2008, $  sec. $4.4.2.$
$\rm[II]$ Plane Answers to Complex Questions: The Theory of Linear Models, Ronald Christensen, Springer Science$+$Business, $2011, $  sec. $2.1.$
